# Why does my void pointer change values in my program?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, void

I have a the following in a header file.

```
struct SortedList
{
    void * data;         
    struct SortedList * next;       
    struct SortedList * previous;
    int (*compareFunc)(void *, void *);
    void (*destructor)(void *);
};
typedef struct SortedList* SortedListPtr;

SortedListPtr SLCreate(CompareFuncT cf, DestructFuncT df);
```

In a .c file, I implemented the SLCreate function.

```
SortedListPtr SLCreate(CompareFuncT cf, DestructFuncT df)
{
    struct SortedList item;         
    item.data = malloc(100);
    item.data = NULL;           
    item.next = (struct SortedList *) malloc(sizeof(struct SortedList));
    item.previous = (struct SortedList *) malloc(sizeof(struct SortedList));
    item.compareFunc = cf;
    item.destructor = df;
    SortedListPtr ptr = (struct SortedList *) malloc(sizeof(struct SortedList));    
    ptr = &item;
    return ptr;
};
```

In main.c, I try to do the following:
    SortedListPtr list = SLCreate(&compareInts, &destroy);

```
//...... A bunch other code that does not alter list or it's contents at all. 



struct SortedList item = (*list);
void * data = item.data;

if (data != NULL)   
{
    printf("Why did data become not null???\n");
}
```

So why is is that data is not null as I directed it in my SLCreate function? I thought I used malloc and what can I do to solve this?

Comment: setting item.data to the return of malloc(), then setting it to NULL throws away the allocated memory. If you want to zero out the memory you allocated, you need to do that. (look up memset)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the address of a local variable, which is undefined behaviour in C.

If you want to return a pointer, the memory it points to must live outside the scope of the function returning it.  Because you are returning a pointer to the local variable `item`, that memory location is no longer available when the function returns.

I think you got mixed up.  You did allocate memory, but copied it incorrectly.

```
SortedListPtr ptr = (struct SortedList *) malloc(sizeof(struct SortedList));    
ptr = &item;
```

Here you replace the pointer with the address of the local `item`.  Instead, that last line should be:

```
*ptr = item;
```

The above will copy all the data stored in `item` to the memory location referenced by `ptr`.

One more thing...  I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be allocating stuff for `previous` and `next`.  Just set them to `NULL`.  I can't be certain without seeing how you plan to use this, but I can see you're confused about pointers.  This would be more "normal":

```
item.next = NULL;
item.previous = NULL;
```

Comment: malloc()ing the structure at the start of the function and setting its members directly would be better practice.

Comment: Yes, certainly.  I guess I didn't feel like typing all that out too.

Comment: since there is no copy constructor in the struct, and pointer is used as member variable, when item is destructored (if there is one), *ptr = item may introduce other problems ?

Comment: @michaeltang This is C, not C++.

Comment: Thanks. So how do you malloc an allocated memory and keep it at null. 
I have a scenario where I can't say *(pointer) = NULL, because pointer points to a struct. However, later on in the program, the pointer gets assigned a random memory which I do not want. I want to maintain it at null. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

may be this way can reduce copy. since i am not sure if you has a copy structor

```
SortedListPtr SLCreate(CompareFuncT cf, DestructFuncT df)
{
    SortedListPtr ptr = (struct SortedList *) malloc(sizeof(struct SortedList));    

    ptr->data = malloc(100);
    ptr->data = NULL;           
    ptr->next = (struct SortedList *) malloc(sizeof(struct SortedList));
    ptr->previous = (struct SortedList *) malloc(sizeof(struct SortedList));
    ptr->compareFunc = cf;
    ptr->destructor = df;
    return ptr;
};
```